# How can I access request MultipartBody information in new Callback<ResponseBody>?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

Hello fellow Android programmers. I am stuck on this problem. I need to retrieve the filename or index of the loop iteration from within a callback method. I am using Retrofit 2.0.

I am thinking I can pass the information into the post as a form field (even if the server doesn't need it), and then retrieve it in the call.request.body() inside the onResponse() method.

If I use the debugger I can see the data. I see the two parts of my form. I am thinking I can add another part in my form that will hold index. However, I don't know how to access this through code. Does anyone know the best way to do this? I want to make sure all images have been uploaded at the end of the last onResponse callback.

Initially i wanted to do this using `call.execute.body()` because I already have a "Please wait dialog"
but that gives me an Exception basically saying I should call the method from inside an asynctask.

Please ignore my attempts at turning the request into a JSON object...

Any ideas help, Thanks!

```
for (File f : theImages) {
    RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), f);
    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", "image.jpg", reqFile);
    RequestBody repId = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), String.valueOf(newExternalReportId));
    uploadCall = hazSnapApi.postImage(body, repId, 1L);
    uploadCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            ResponseBody rBody = response.body();
            RequestBody mRequest = call.request().body();
            try {
                String temp = call.request().toString();
                JSONObject bodyAsJson = new JSONObject(call.request().toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a Services that creates a retrofit call. This way I can just do `call.execute.body()`.
This works because Service does not run on main thread.